# Significance of repeated use of Irma Thomas's song 'Anyone Who Knows What Love Is'?

Tags: analysis, soundtrack, black-mirror

In *Black Mirror*, Irma Thomas's song 'Anyone Who Knows What Love Is' got featured a lot:

- In *Fifteen Million Merits*: Abi sings "Anyone Who Knows What Love Is" for the judges.
- In *White Christmas*, song is used in a karaoke segment.
- In *Men Against Fire*, Hunter sings this song in Heidekker's farmhouse while holding him at gunpoint.
- In *Crocodile*, while the insurance lady was driving
- *Rachel, Jack and Ashley* Too - The song is extracted from Ashley O's brain during her coma and produced by her managers through speech synthesis.
- *Joan Is Awful* - The song is played in the background when Joan enters a bar to meet Mac.

But why is this real life song used so prominently? Is there any significance of the song to a *Black Mirror* theme?

Answer (score 9):

It's [simply an Easter Egg](https://decider.com/2016/11/03/netflix-black-mirror-charlie-brooker-annabel-jones-interview/):

> When asked if they had a favorite Season Three Easter Egg, Brooker
> immediately mentioned “Nosedive.” “I think my favorite, currently, is
> the status update from Michael Callow [the Prime Minister in “The
> National Anthem“] that appears in ‘Nosedive’ because I had forgotten
> that I typed it in, and I thought it hadn’t made it into the finished
> show,” he said. “Somebody found it and screen-capped it where he says,
> he’s sort of moaning about being thrown out of a zoo.”
>
> **Brooker also added that he enjoyed Irma Thomas’ “Anyone Who Knows What
> Love Is (Will Understand)” reappearing in “Men Against Fire.”** The song
> is known in the series for Abi’s (Jessica Brown Findlay) haunting
> performance of it on the reality show Hot Shot in “Fifteen Million
> Merits.”

Also from [DigitalSpy - Charlie Brooker explains how one huge Black Mirror easter egg links several episodes](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a849883/black-mirror-easter-egg-explained-charlie-brooker-irma-thomas-song/)

> First heard in season one's 'Fifteen Million Merits', Irma Thomas'
> 1964 track 'Anyone Who Knows What Love Is (Will Understand)' has
> actually been played numerous times throughout the series.
>
> Also appearing in 'White Christmas', Season 3's 'Men Against Fire',
> and Season 4's 'Crocodile', the showrunners confirming that **ties the episodes into an "artistic universe".**
>
> "It was originally selected for ['Fifteen Million Merits'] because it
> was, it has the sound of a timeless haunting classic, yet wouldn't be
> familiar to most viewers," Brooker told TheWrap. "Idea was to have the
> character of Abi sing a song of earnest beauty."
>
> His co-showrunner Annabel Jones explained that he "has loved [the
> song] for a long time", adding that they return to it constantly
> because Brooker "liked the idea of nesting all the episodes together
> in an artistic universe of sorts".

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the update!